# Moving back my question to MO

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration, meta

[References on Gerbes](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3671/references-on-gerbes) question [is migrated from MO to meta](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/296693/timeline).

It was never about MO. I was only giving information about search I have done. None of the comments except one has objection with this. None of the answers says anything about MO. I have even taken that users objection and removed information about MO.

Can it go back to MO now?

Comment: I have added (specific-question) tag - see [the tag-info](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/specific-question/info) for more details on this tag. If your intention was to ask about *general question* and your question only serves as an example, feel free to remove the tag. (But the way your question is phrased, I understand it as a question related only to this specific situation.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for the tag. I am asking for only my question

Comment: I suppose you will need help from moderators to do this. It seems to be slightly delicate problem, at least I'd guess so based on looking at some posts related to this: [Why can't mods undo a migration from main site X to Meta X?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285804) and [Allow diamond moderators to reverse question migrations?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35744)

Comment: Also these posts seem somewhat related: [Migrations can be unilaterally rejected by OP under certain conditions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247536) and [Migration to per-site meta should not be reversed by closing or deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133524)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I have asked for moderator attention. Did not get any response. If I delete here does it get migrated back?

Comment: You cannot delete your question since it has an upvoted answer. (For all the details see: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)) The most reasonable course of action is, in my opinion, to wait a bit to see what the moderators do with the question.

Comment: I will wait for moderators reply.. @MartinSleziak

Comment: For what it's worth, I, too, have flagged for moderator attention.

Comment: Deleting, when you can do it, just deletes; it doesn't do anything else.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks.

Comment: Now that the issue has been solved, wouldn't it make sense for this question to be deleted? It is way too particular in order to be of any use to the readers of this site.

Comment: My opinion: I don't think giving information about search you have done is appropriate content for a question. I mean not specifically for MO, but in general. Giving information is something opposite to asking a question, which one does when one needs to receive information, not give it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question on MathOverflow has been restored.

The corresponding question on Meta.MathOverflow has been deleted.

Comment: A link to the new location would be nice.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296693/references-on-gerbes @GerryMyerson

Comment: Just out of curiosity, the way to achieve this was simply deletion of the migrated version, as suggested in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285804/why-cant-mods-undo-a-migration-from-main-site-x-to-meta-x/285805#285805) (and some other posts)?

Comment: @MartinSleziak That is correct.

Comment: If the question has now been deleted, can this post be updated to reflect that?