# Possible bug in migration

Tags: bug, migration

[Moving back my question to MO](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3675/moving-back-my-question-to-mo/3677#3677)

I have given link for question as [References on Gerbes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296693/references-on-gerbes). This I have done using my computer.

Now when I check it from my iPad It is taking me back to meta question.

I could not attach screenshot as image size limit is only 2 MB.

You can check this by clicking on the link that I have given as comment to answer for this question  [Moving back my question to MO](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3675/moving-back-my-question-to-mo/3677#3677). At least the link description being MathOverflow.net/—- says it has to be from MO. When I click from my iPad it is showing meta question.

Comment: The post was migrated back to MO and then deleted.

Comment: I know that but link for MO question is still giving meta question @ToddTrimble

Comment: More likely is that the link is to a cached copy in your browser. Gerhard "Clearing Browser Cache Solves Much" Paseman, 2018.04.03.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, it appears that this problem has been resolved.

Comment: Yes, it is resolved. Thank you :)